# setup test domain ready for site launch

Tags: subdomain, testing

I'm about to launch a site on a live server, after developing it with xampp on localhost. I first want to test the site before i make it live. How do i setup this up so I have it in a subdomain (i.e. test.livesite.com)? Is it just set it up on the server and only add the cname dns setting? Or is there a better way?

All i am trying to do is add my site to the server, so i can edit it and look at it before I set it as live.

Comment: thanks for the tip John, I didnt realise what I had to do, all sorted now thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted. We're happy to have you as part of our community. :)

Comment: do i need to repost this or will people still be able to see the question as i'm still desperate to solve this thanks, think I will try the cname approach

Comment: Not at all. Your question is still active. It just appears as though no one has an answer to your question yet. Maybe if you edit it and add some more information about what you are trying to do and what you've tried so far, if anything, and see if that helps to solicit a response/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, adding a subdomain is just a server configuration matter. For example, if you are using hostgator, within 3 clicks you can have a well configured, ready to use, subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved a few ways.

Most hosting environments will automatically set up your site that is accessible by IP and username, you could use that.

If they don't do that then you could set up a domain as you suggest.